# Why label.getY()-10 could move up the component instead of move down?

Tags: java, swing, math, awt

here are the codes, just wondering why the componments could move up with "getY()-10", with learning some Math concepts, I assume it should be "getY() +10".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)

...

```
public class UpAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX(),label.getY()+10);
        }
    }

public class DownAction extends AbstractAction{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setLocation(label.getX(),label.getY()-10);
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the standard coordinate layout of containers in Java. The origin is at top left.  Additionally, when you specify the location of a component or draw a figure such as an oval or rectangle, the bounds that describe the component placement or figure use the same coordinate system.  So a circle would extend down and to the right from its specified `(x,y)` location.

[image]

Comment: See also [_Graphics2D: Coordinate Spaces_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)